# Set Column Value Based on Calculate Condition from Each Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have a empty dataframe as

```
columns_name = list(str(i) for i in range(10))
dfa = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dfa['Count'] = [10, 6, 9, 4]
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 10 |
| B | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 6 |
| C | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 9 |
| D | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4 |

I want to replace `Nan` values with a symbol with the difference of `max(Count) - Current(max)`.
So, the final result will look like.

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 10 |
| B | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | - | - | - | - | 6 |
| C | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | - | 9 |
| D | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | - | - | - | - | - | - | 4 |

I am stuck at

`dfa.at[dfa.index, [str(col) for col in list(range(dfa['Count'].max() - dfa['Count']))]] = '-'`

and getting `KeyError: 'Count'`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your this part of the code `dfa.at[dfa.index, [str(col) for col in list(range(dfa['Count'].max() - dfa['Count']))]] = '-'` has issue.

Just try to create the list which you are trying to use inside comprehension

```py
list(range(dfa['Count'].max() - dfa['Count']))
```

It'll throw `TypeError`

If you notice, you'll figure out that `(dfa['Count'].max() - dfa['Count'])` will give following `series`:

```py
A    0
B    4
C    1
D    6
```

And since you're trying to pass a `series` to python's `range` function, it will throw the error.

One possible solution might be:

```py
for index, cols in zip(dfa.index, [list(map(str, col)) for col in (dfa).apply(lambda x: list(range(x['Count'], dfa['Count'].max())), axis=1).values]):
    dfa.loc[index, cols] = '-'
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
Out[315]: 
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  Count
A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     10
B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -    -    -    -      6
C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -      9
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -    -    -    -    -    -      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting is also an option:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns_name = list(str(i) for i in range(10))
dfa = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dfa['Count'] = [10, 6, 9, 4]

# Broadcast based on column index (Excluding Count)
m = (
        dfa['Count'].to_numpy()[:, None] == np.arange(0, dfa.shape[1] - 1)
).cumsum(axis=1).astype(bool)
# Grab Columns To Update
non_count_columns = dfa.columns[dfa.columns != 'Count']
# Update based on mask
dfa[non_count_columns] = dfa[non_count_columns].mask(m, '-')

print(dfa)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  Count
A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     10
B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -    -    -    -      6
C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -      9
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    -    -    -    -    -    -      4
```